# What does "でいる" mean?

Tags: verbs, nominalization

I've heard the sentence "一人でいるのが好きです", meaning "I like to be alone".

Is this a substitute of "です", could I for example say "学生でいるのが好きです"? If so, how is it different from "である"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66270/what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-and-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-in-this-example

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks a lot