# what does いたまえ mean and how was it conjugated?

Tags: words, etymology, conjugations, sentence

I was wondering what does いたまえ mean
I really don't know the main word when I searched and I don't know how it was conjugated
this sentence was from oregairu season 1 ep 4 near the start

好きな者達と組んでもらうから そのつもりでいたまえ

Comment: The main verb is いる. For でいる, see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66270/5010). そのつもりでいろ means "Keep that in mind", "Prepare yourself (mentally)" etc.

Comment: so is たまえ just たまう＝to grant so both of them together いたまえ you need to grant/give?

Comment: This type of たまえ is basically just a mild imperative. You can think of it as a pompous variant of てください.